# Ansible postgresql_db task fails after a very long pause

Tags: postgresql, ansible

The following ansible task (in a vagrant VM) fails :

```
- name: ensure database is created
  postgresql_db: name={{dbname}}
  sudo_user: postgres
```

the task pauses for a few minutes before failing
the vagrant VM is a centos6.5.1, 
the tasks output is :

```
TASK: [postgresql | ensure database is created] ******************************* 
fatal: [192.168.78.6] => failed to parse: 
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo via ansible, key=glxzviadepqkwddapvjheeuillbdakly] password: 


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

I have verified that postgres is prooperly installed 
by doing vagrant ssh and connecting vial psql.

I also validated that I can do a "sudo su postgres" within the VM ...

### ========  update

It looks like the problem is the sudo_user: postgres, because removing the
above postgres tasks and replacing with this one causes the same problem :

```
- name: say hello from postgress
  command: echo "hello"
  sudo_user: postgres
```

the output is exactly the same as above, so it's really a problem of 
ansible doing a sudo_user on centos6.5

one interesting observation, although I can do  "sudo su postgres" from
inside the vm

when I call "psql" (as the postgres user) I get the message :

could not change directory to "/home/vagrant": Permission denied

but the psql shell still starts successfully

### ========  conclusion

Problem was fixed by changing to a stock centos box,

lesson learned : when using ansible/vagrant, only use stock OS images...

Comment: "failed to parse" sounds like ansible had problems parsing your hosts file.  Can you post what you have in your hosts file regarding the host that this is running on?  Also, any output by running the command with -vvvv would also be helpful.

Comment: I wrote an update above, the content of the hosts file looks pretty normal, it's : 127.0.0.1   stmapp localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

Comment: since the problem is not about postgres, I created another question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321151/ansible-sudo-user-hangs-for-a-few-minutes-and-then-fails-in-a-centos6-5-1-vagra

Comment: Max, please be more specific with your solution. What is the URL to the box you are using?

Comment: The problem was encountered with this box : https://github.com/2creatives/vagrant-centos/releases/tag/v6.5.1 and this other box does not have the problem : https://github.com/NREL/vagrant-boxes

Comment: I had this exact same issue, thanks a bunch for your write up!

Comment: You should post your conclusion as an answer and then accept it so this question no longer shows up as unanswered in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the [wait for](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/wait_for_module.html) host:

```
- local_action: wait_for port=22 host="{{PosgresHost}}" search_regex=OpenSSH delay=1 timeout=60
  ignore_errors: yes
```

PS:

I think you should use gather_facts: False and do setup after ssh is up.
Example main.yml:

```
---
- name: Setup
  hosts: all
  #connection: local
  user: root
  gather_facts: False
  roles:
    - main
```

Example roles/main/tasks/main.yml

```
- debug: msg="System {{ inventory_hostname }} "
- local_action: wait_for port=22 host="{{ inventory_hostname}}" search_regex=OpenSSH delay=1 timeout=60
  ignore_errors: yes
- action: setup
```

ansible-playbook -i 127.0.0.1, main.yml

```
PLAY [Setup] ******************************************************************

TASK: [main | debug msg="System {{ inventory_hostname }} "] *******************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "System 127.0.0.1 "
}

TASK: [main | wait_for port=22 host="{{ inventory_hostname}}" search_regex=OpenSSH delay=1 timeout=60] ***
ok: [127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```