# ansible sudo_user hangs for a few minutes and then fails (in a centos6.5.1 vagrant vm)

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I have these two simple tasks :

```
- name: I am 
  shell: "echo `id`"

- name: say hello
  shell: echo "postgres saying hello"
  sudo_user: postgres
```

The second task fails after a long pause, the output is below
(it's runing with vagrant with the verbose level vvv)
(yes I have verified that the user postgres exists,
I can do a sudo su postgres from inside the VM)

```
TASK: [postgresql | I am] ***************************************************** 
changed: [192.168.78.6] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo `id` ", "delta": "0:00:00.002511", "end": "2014-01-23 22:49:14.161249", "item": "", "rc": 0, "start": "2014-01-23 22:49:14.158738", "stderr": "", "stdout": "uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)"}

TASK: [postgresql | say hello] ************************************************ 
fatal: [192.168.78.6] => failed to parse: [sudo via ansible, key=fnfgfnxabemrzbfixwgoksvgjrfzplxf] password: 


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

The thing runs in a centos6.5.1 vagrant vm

Comment: Not sure but I think you need also a '  sudo : True' in the say hello action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work apparently for Centos6.5. The supposition is that it is unable to get past a prompt for the postgres system user password, though that is speculation.

In answer to the question how to overcome the inability of ansible to sudo to postgres (which in turn would use peer authentication via the default pg_hba.conf configuration) during the postgresql_* commands, here is a workaround:

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - lineinfile: dest='/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf' regexp="^local\s+all\s+all\s+peer$" line="local    all        all                      trust" backrefs=yes

    - name: restart after line change
      action: shell sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.3 restart

    - name: create database
      postgresql_db: name=acme
      sudo: no                         # NB!!
      sudo_user: postgres
```

We are changing local access from `peer` to `trust` which needs to be removed after the required operations are performed either by another `lineinfile` or replacing the file using md5 or whatever the desired configuration is followed by a restart. The above is clearly for demonstration only. This is a massive hack but will allow you to issue ansible postgresql module commands that work under Centos6. Note that we set `sudo` off for the postgresql task.

I confirmed the problem exists and the hack works for this vm box:

```
https://github.com/2creatives/vagrant-centos/releases/download/v6.5.1/centos65-x86_64-20131205.box
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue may be in the sudoers configuration. I was having a problem identical to this one on a Debian 7.6 box that had the following line in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

After I changed that line to the following:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Ansible started working as expected, i.e. it was able to execute tasks as the `postgres` user using `sudo`.